# re-assign jquery ajax capability to manipulated element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function in JS called AssignAJAXEvents() with the following setup:

```
function AssignAJAXEvents(containerSelector)
{
    containerSelector = containerSelector || 'body';

    $("input[type='submit']",containerSelector).filter('.ajax').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
        var container = $(this).closest('*.lc');

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function(){ $(loading).show(); },
            timeout: 60000, // 60 seconds
            error: function() { },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: post_data,
            url: "/ajax.php?Ajax&Page=" + page + "&" + action_name + "=" + action_value,
            success: function(data) {
                $(loading).hide();

                container.hide().replaceWith(data).show();

                AssignAJAXEvents(container);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    AssignAJAXEvents();
});
```

When the page loads initially the function loads the events to the "body", which is the entire element.. when the ajax call is complete I would like to load this event only to the affected container.. otherwise it wastes resources on already assigned events and the entire "body" matched elements will be affected.

How can I assign this event only to the newly populated container?

Comment: you have argument to pass element into function, why can't you use that?

Comment: Because the 'container' is a jQuery object, not pre-determent; looks for the closest "*.lc" and this is the container;

Comment: So you want to `unbind` the `.click` handler? You are already doing that in your code, so just have it unbind everything before you call your function again. Or better yet, just use the `.one()` function so that it'll automatically be removed.

Comment: Its not about the handler that I am concerned about, it is about how to assign the event to $("input[type='submit']",container) which is the populated container..

Answer (score 0):

```
function AssignAJAXEvents(containerSelector)
{
    containerSelector = containerSelector || 'body';

    $("input[type='submit']",containerSelector).filter('.ajax').one('click',function(){
    var container = $(this).closest('*.lc');
     $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){ $(loading).show(); },
        timeout: 60000, // 60 seconds
        error: function() { },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: post_data,
        url: "/ajax.php?Ajax&Page=" + page + "&" + action_name + "=" + action_value,
        success: function(data) {
            $(loading).hide();
            container.hide().replaceWith(data).show();
            AssignAJAXEvents(container);
        }
    });

    return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I dont want to unbind it, the reason why i am unbinding it is not to duplicate the event handler as its scope is the "body" and every-time this event gets triggered "body" elements get assigned the event again. When I try " AssignAJAXEvents(container);" the script doesn't work at all.. please try this for yourself.